# history.push('/something') does push, but does not render the component because of exitBeforeEnter property of Animate Presence of framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I am trying to navigate to /main from postActions after deleting a post from PostDetail.

[Code showing action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZoao.png)

It pushes the /main but doesn't render the main component.

[code showing where the problem occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xDlw.png)

However this does work if I am opting out exitBeforeEnter property of framer-motion on AnimatePresence.

[Code showing partial solution by removing exitBeforeEnter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjWB4.png)

This causes animations for new component and exiting component at the same time.

Is there any way to use exitBeforeEnter and pushed component to render ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your exiting component have an exit prop? AnimatePresence with enterBeforeExit will not render the new component if the previous one does not exit with an exit animation.

Comment: Yes it does have exit prop.